# Вывод профиля пользователя в Java Servlet

Tags: java, веб-программирование, jsp, servlet

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно реализовать ссылку на конкретного пользователя с учётом его ID? То есть на данный момент у каждого пользователя есть свой профиль, он может его редактировать, но у всех он доступен по ссылке "/profile". А как можно сделать так, чтобы один пользователь мог просматривать профиль другого пользователя? Есть идея, чтобы сервлет обрабатывал ссылку "/profile?id=${userId}", но не знаю, как это реализовать.
На данный момент пытаюсь получить id пользователя следующим образом:
 `<c:set var="userProfile" value="${userProfile.userId}"/>
<a href="/Server/userProfile?id=${userProfile}"  style="color:black">Привет, ${userProfile}</a>`
Однако, в таком варианте, он выдает ошибку:
`org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [index.jsp] at line [78]`
Однако без данного урла, получение userId не вызывает проблем и он с ним "здоровается".
Как можно правильно реализовать активную ссылку на профиль пользователя?

Comment: А в чем проблема считывать параметры запроса в сервлете?

Comment: Ну вот я и прошу помощи, как это реализовать. До меня пока не дошло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://localhost:8080/yourContextPath/profile?id=1`

Для того, чтобы считать `id` пользователя нужно вызвать метод `httpServletRequest.getParameter("id")`, который, в данном случае, вернет `"1"`.

---

Сейчас более популярен другой стиль, а именно URL

`http://localhost:8080/yourContextPath/profiles`

вернет список всех пользователей, а URL

`http://localhost:8080/yourContextPath/profiles/1`

вернет пользователя с `id = 1`.

Для того, чтобы это реализовать необходимо "смапить" сервлет по адресу `/profiles` и вызвать метод `httpServletRequest.getPathInfo()`, который вернет `null` для /profiles и `"/1"` для "/profiles/1". Соответственно, можно получить `id` пользователя.

**UPDATE:**

```
@WebServlet("/profiles")
public UserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String str = request.getPathInfo();
        if (str == null) {
            // Выводим список пользователей
        }
        else {
            Long id = Long.valueOf(str.substring(1));
            // Выводим пользователя по id
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: Сейчас столкнулся с проблемой. ID пользователя из запроса я получаю,по ссылке переходит хорошо, но:  
Так как нет обработчика для ссылки profiles/id он перекидывает меня на дефолтный сервлет (главную страницу) и не хочет ничего делать. Пытаюсь обработать запрос с ID так:  
`if (request.getServletPath().length() > 6) {
   String id = request.getServletPath().substring(7);
   if (id != null) {  
тут логика получения из БД объекта и отправка в request.setAttribute()    
коммаентарии не дают все вставить
}`  
Подскажите пожалуйста,как быть?

Comment: Проблема решилась тем,что я могу обрабатывать такой запрос в дефолтном сервлете. То есть в сервлете, отвечающим за главную страницу. Вопрос в следующем,а возможно ли сделать как-то изящнее,чтобы все такие запросы обрабатывались в другом сервлете USersList? Или вариант только переадресовывать запрос на тот сервлет?

Comment: @МишаковАлександр я обновил ответ.